# How to change output coding of a XML of reading and writing at the same time in with Jdom?

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, jdom

I have this code, I want to read and want to write the "prueba3.xml" at the same time, the file is UTF8 but when I write the file, the encoding changes and displays strange characters, although I have added `format.setEncoding("UTF-8")`, it is not doing it correctly. Is it possible to change the output encoding to UTF8 with jdom `SAXBuilder`?

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prueba>
    <reg id="576340">
         <dato cant="856" id="6" val="-1" num="" desc="ñápás" />
         <dato cant="680" id="1" val="-1" num="" desc="résd" />
         <dato cant="684" id="5" val="-1" num="" desc="..да и вообем" />
         <dato cant="1621" id="1" val="-1" num="" desc="hi" />
         <dato cant="1625" id="5" val="-1" num="" desc="Hola" />
   </reg>
</prueba>
```

This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, JDOMException, IOException
{
    //Se crea un SAXBuilder para poder parsear el archivo
    File xml = new File("c:\\prueba3.xml");
    Document doc = (Document) new SAXBuilder().build(xml);

    Element raiz = doc.getRootElement();
    //Recorremos los hijos de la etiqueta raíz  
    List articleRow = raiz.getChildren("reg");

    for (int i = 0; i < articleRow.size(); i++) {

        Element row = (Element) articleRow.get(i);
        List images = row.getChildren("dato");

         for (int j = 0; j < images.size(); j++) {

             Element row2 = (Element) images.get(j);
             String texto = row2.getAttributeValue("desc") ;
             String id = row2.getAttributeValue("id"); 

                   if ((texto != null) && (texto !="") && (id.equals("1"))){
                     row2.getAttribute("desc").setValue("Raúl").toString();
                   }
        }

        Format format = Format.getRawFormat();
        format.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(format);
        xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(format);
        xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("c:\\prueba3.xml"));
    }

    System.out.println("fin");   
}
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prueba>
  <reg id="576340">
       <dato cant="856" id="6" val="-1" num="" desc="s" /> 
       <dato cant="680" id="1" val="-1" num="" desc="Ra/>
       <dato cant="684" id="5" val="-1" num="" desc="..?? ? ??????" />
       <dato cant="1621" id="1" val="-1" num="" desc="Ra/>
       <dato cant="1625" id="5" val="-1" num="" desc="Hola" />
 </reg>
</prueba>
```

Greetings and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relatively common problem to encounter when using JDOM - especially in countries/regions with non-latin alphabets. In some senses I regret maintaining the use of `Writer` outputs at all in JDOM.

See the JavaDoc on XMLOutputter too: http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html

The issue is that `FileWriter` uses the default encoding of the system to convert from the Writer to the underlying byte data. JDOM cannot control that conversion.

If you change the line of code:

> ```
> xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("c:\\prueba3.xml"));
> ```

to use an `OutputStream` instead of a `Writer`:

```
try (OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\prueba3.xml")) {
    xmlOutput.output(doc, fos);
}
```

... it will use the output as a byte-stream, and the systems' default encoding won't interfere with the output.

(P.S. There's no reason to assign the `xmlOutput` instance twice.)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, now it works correctly, that simple seems now, that you explained it to me XD. Greetings.